# MYSQL update with nested subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have 3 tables in this format:

Table Child:

```
id|parent_id|grandparent_id
1  1         null
2  2         null
3  3         null
```

---

Table Parent:

```
id|grandparent_id
1          1
2          1
3          2
```

---

Table GrandParent:

```
id
1          
2
```

I need to run a query that updates grandparent_id column in Child table based on the grandparent_id in Parent table. So the correct final form of Child table will be:
Table Child:

```
id|parent_id|grandparent_id
1  1         1
2  2         1
3  3         2
```

This is the query I have at the moment but it returns more than 1 row which is wrong:

```
update child set grandparent_id = (
  select gpd.id from GrandParent gp, Parent p 
  where p.grandparent_id = gp.id) 
where 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Child SET Child.grandparent_id = (
    SELECT GrandParent.id 
    FROM GrandParent INNER JOIN Parent ON GrandParent.id = Parent.grandparent_id
    WHERE Parent.id = parent_id
) WHERE Child.grandparent_id IS NULL;
```

> **Demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/894e97/1/0 *(modified table content to show the `UPDATE` is working)*.
>
> **Hint:** Your *"correct"* example is wrong: `GrandParent` of `Parent` with `id = 2` is `1`!

Comment: Thanks it worked. So instead of normal join I had to Inner join? and why can't I just say where 1 to run it on everything even when it's not null?

Comment: If you want to `UPDATE` all Childs you don't need the `WHERE` part and you can remove it (no need for `WHERE 1`). I would choose the `INNER JOIN` to join the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try on the below query:

```
Update child c,parent p
set c.grandparent_id = p.grandparent_id
where c.id = parent.id 
and c.grandparent_id = ' '
```